# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT CONCAT_WS and handle NULL values

Tags: mysql, null, case, group-concat, concat-ws

How to handle rows with NULL values especial from here (this is only one place when values can be NULL, because products don't have any attributes):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CONCAT_WS (': ', GroupAttrLang.`name`, AttrLang.`name`)) ORDER BY AttrLang.`name` ASC
```

This is part from my BIG query:

```
SELECT
TProduct.`reference` AS ProdReference,
ProdLang.`name` AS ProductName,
ProdLang.`description` AS ProdDesc,
ROUND((TProduct.`price`*1.23)/4.1989,2) AS ProductPrice,

CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(ProdAttr.`id_product`) = 0 THEN 1 
    ELSE (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CONCAT_WS (': ', GroupAttrLang.`name`, AttrLang.`name`)) ORDER BY AttrLang.`name` ASC)) 
END AS ProdAttributes,

/*IF ((COUNT(ProdAttr.`id_product`) > 0), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CONCAT_WS (': ', GroupAttrLang.`name`, AttrLang.`name`)) ORDER BY AttrLang.`name` ASC) , 'n/a' ) AS ProdAttributes,*/

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CONCAT_WS (' - ', ParLang.`name`, CatLang.`name` ))) AS ProdFit 
    FROM `ps_product` AS TProduct
        LEFT JOIN `ps_category_product` AS CatProd ON CatProd.`id_product` = TProduct.`id_product`

        LEFT JOIN `ps_category` AS Cat ON Cat.`id_category` = CatProd.`id_category`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` AS ParLang ON Cat.`id_parent` = ParLang.`id_category`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` AS ProdLang ON ProdLang.`id_product` = TProduct.`id_product`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` AS CatLang ON CatLang.`id_category` = CatProd.`id_category`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute` AS ProdAttr ON ProdAttr.`id_product` = TProduct.`id_product`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute_combination` AS ProdAttrComb ON ProdAttrComb.`id_product_attribute` = ProdAttr.`id_product_attribute`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute` AS TAttr ON TAttr.`id_attribute` = ProdAttrComb.`id_attribute`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_group_lang` AS GroupAttrLang ON GroupAttrLang.`id_attribute_group` = TAttr.`id_attribute_group`
        LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_lang` AS AttrLang ON AttrLang.`id_attribute` = TAttr.`id_attribute`
    WHERE 
        Cat.`id_parent` != 1 AND 
        ProdLang.`id_lang`=1 AND
        CatLang.`id_lang` = 1 AND
        GroupAttrLang.`id_lang` = 1 AND
        AttrLang.`id_lang` = 1
             GROUP BY TProduct.`reference` ORDER BY TProduct.`reference` ASC;
```

Everything working except handle a NULL values from a listing above. I tried 
**IF** statement result was the same, query skip rows with NULL values.
I try make a single query with only one thing to print:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(ProdAttr.`id_product`) > 0 THEN COUNT(ProdAttr.`id_product`)
    ELSE 'n/a'
END AS ProdAttrList
FROM `ps_product` AS TProduct 
    LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute` AS ProdAttr ON ProdAttr.`id_product`=TProduct.`id_product` 
        GROUP BY TProduct.`reference`;
```

And that working perfect, see image [PrtSc. of last listing](http://forum.4programmers.net/Bazy_danych/211468-wymuszenie_wyswietlenia_wiersza_pomimo_concat_ws_null?mode=download&id=3548)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must change **WHERE** statement:

```
...WHERE
GroupAttrLang.`id_lang` = 1 AND
AttrLang.`id_lang` = 1...
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_group_lang` AS GroupAttrLang ON GroupAttrLang.`id_attribute_group` = TAttr.`id_attribute_group` AND GroupAttrLang.`id_lang` = 1
LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_lang` AS AttrLang ON AttrLang.`id_attribute` = TAttr.`id_attribute` AND AttrLang.`id_lang` = 1
```

Problem SOLVED, you can now export catalog of products from your prestashop.